# can $f$ be holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a complex valued function of the form $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.
>
> Suppose that $u(x,y)=3x^2y$.
>
> Then
>
> 1. $f$ cannot be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ for any choice of $v$.
> 2. $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ for a suitable choice of $v$.
> 3. $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ for all choices of $v$.
> 4. $u$ is not differentiable.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGGug.png))

well, I have calculated by applying CR equation, getting the option $1$ is correct? could anyone tell me  just am I right?thank you.

Comment: I think it would be better (esp. for people with certain browser limitations) to just copy the text of the problem rather than posting an image.

Comment: show more work. How did you apply CR.

Comment: I really do not understand your problem:  for people with certain browser limitations, meaning?could you tell me?

Comment: @Kuttus: Regardless of browser limitations, the typed text is **far** easier to read than the scan you used. A nicer scan would be more acceptable.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I agree, please pardon me for this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u and v must satisfy laplace equation if f is a holomorphic function.Any v of course don't
satisfy laplace equation. hence 1 is correct. infact a form of v can be calculated by integrating the CR eequations